# MySQL Inner join with where on multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a SQL solution for the following:

Lets say I have one table named "TRIPS"

```
[  id ][ Name  ][ Duration]
[  1  ][ Trip1 ][   12    ]
[  2  ][ Trip2 ][   16    ]
[  3  ][ Trip3 ][   5     ]
```

And another table with countries each TRIP visits: LOCATIONS

```
[  tripId ][ country ]
[    1    ][    US   ] <--
[    1    ][    PA   ] <--
[    1    ][    RU   ]
[    2    ][    US   ] <--
[    2    ][    PA   ] <--
[    3    ][    PA   ]
[    3    ][    RU   ]
```

Now I want all the TRIPS which visitis "US" and "PA".
So the result will be 1 and 2 becouse they both visit US and PA.

I thought I could use INNER JOIN but that only takes one row in the LOCATIONS table (afaik)

Can someone help me?

***[EDIT]***

I have it working with this ugly way:

```
SELECT * ,group_concat(distinct(LOCATIONS.country) separator ',') as COUNTRYCODES 
FROM TRIPS left join LOCATIONS on TRIPS.id = LOCATIONS.tripid  
group by TRIPS.id 
having COUNTRYCODES like '%PA%' and COUNTRYCODES like '%US%';
```

But I think using "like" is an ugly solution

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *, COUNT(DISTINCT tripID) AS cnt
FROM TRIPS
LEFT JOIN LOCATIONS ON TRIPS.id = LOCATIONS.tripID
WHERE LOCATIONS.country IN ('US', 'PA')
GROUP BY TRIPS.id
HAVING cnt = 2
```

Basically, get all records where the trip was to PA or US, count how many trips were made, and return only those where BOTH countries were visited.

Comment: I cant get it to work.

I get only one row with this QUERY with a count of all the rows it finds.So, if it finds 20 rows, the cnt = 20.

"SELECT *, COUNT(DISTINCT tripID) AS cnt
FROM TRIPS
LEFT JOIN LOCATIONS ON TRIPS.id = LOCATIONS.tripID
WHERE LOCATIONS.country IN ('US', 'PA')"